# Localhost error in wamp server

Tags: apache, localhost, wamp

I have installed WAMP server and changed port 80 to another because it is used by IIS
but when i type localhost:82 it can't be found,
the problem is that apache is not running and i don't know why?port 82 is not used
any solutions?

Comment: did you change port for apache or iis ?

Comment: i changed port for apache

Comment: oh ok, and you mention apache isnt running ? you dont know why ? what does it do when you try to run apache?

Comment: apache icon is orange and say that server is online when i type localhost:82 say that page is not available

Comment: well i think there are two options, if the icon is still orange its because its still trying to use port 80 and thats taken.. you can trying to shutdown iis if you are not using and restart apache or change port for listening for apache correctly.

Comment: did you change the port in the httpd.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the icon is orange something is interfering with the port. Maybe another service is using port 82 as well. If you're going to use Apache might as well disable IIS.

**Disable IIS**

stop and disable the www service

type services.msc from the run command prompt > scroll down to World Wide Publishing service.

or go to control panel > Administrative Tools > Services.msc > World Wide Publishing service.

**Enable Apache**

restart apache with the original port.